# Как выровнять блок с тенью?

Tags: css

Юзеры могут создавать рандомные блоки и задавать этим блокам свойства. Одно из свойств это тень

`filter: drop-shadow(30px 10px 1px #4444dd)`

Проблема в том, что смещение тени в право может быть 5px что ок, так и 25px, что в принципе тоже ок, но в данном случае создаётся визуальное чувство что блок не по центру а как то прижат к право стороне. Как то так[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли как нибудь выровнять все это дело по простому? Пока что на ум приходит только высчитать насколько тень в право ушла, и настолько же блок в лево двинуть.

Comment: А если там blur?

Comment: И да и нет, можно самому эти дела регулировать.

Comment: "вправо". "влево".  только на половину от смещения.